# how to use class from another package

Tags: php

I hava two folder in php such as package1 and package2. In package1 there is class A. I want to create object of class A in Class B which is available in package2 without using include and require.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use autoloading.

Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php

You can also use a third party autoloader, compose provides one that lets you add folders to its configuration file. You also get the benefits of composer this way, which if you do not know about I suggest you research it.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading